# Can only boot into Recovery Mode on Nexus 9. Is there a way to recover my files before doing a factory reset?

Tags: recovery-mode, nexus-9

An update broke my Nexus 9 last week, so now when I try to boot it tells me it's corrupted and then shows a "No Command" screen. I assume I'll have to do a factory reset, and if that doesn't work I'll send it into HTC. However, before I do one of those and erase the drive, I'd like to try to copy my AK Notepad files off of it if at all possible.

I can boot into Recovery Mode. I've googled and found that some Droids have a Backup option on this menu, but apparently not the Nexus 9. Also, as it's still under warranty I don't want to root it. Is it possible to get my files back?

Comment: You can root your device, push custom recovery via computer and backup data using custom recovery. You may find all the resources @ forum.xdadevelopers.com

Comment: Flash twrp recovery then enable MTP and then backup your files

Comment: You can also download the system image from Google and flash it